# How do I generate a random email in Robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to generate a random email Id for my test data

Comment: You can get a random string using the string generator in the String Library. Take a look at the documentation: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Generate%20Random%20String

Comment: Trying how? What research have you done so far? What exactly isn't working with anything you've attempted? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the faker library for robot framework. You should by able to generate variouse random data with it. Here is a [link](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-faker/)